# Inverse with Extended Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: cryptography, euclidean-algorithm, numerical-calculus

I'm solving a task from https://www.coursera.org/learn/crypto/, particularly the following question:

[image]

I know that 3x - 5 = 0 and since "ax + b = 0" that implies "x = -b * a^-1", meaning we need to compute the inverse a^-1. Since a=3, we can compute inverse of it via two ways:

- **Formula: x^-1 = x^(p-2) mod p**: 3^-1 = 3⁽19-2) mod 19 = 13
- **Extended Euclidean Algorithm**: I'm not sure why I don't also get 13 when using this algorithm:

  ```
   19 = 3(6) + 1
   3 = 1(3) + 0

   therefore

   1 = 19 - 3(6)
  ```

  So the answer is 6, but that does not match 13 as above, which is the correct answer. Why doesn't Extended Euclidean Algorithm work when computing the inverse 3^-1?

Comment: If you rewrite as $3(6) + 1 = 19$ then it should be clear that $3(6) \equiv -1 \pmod{19},$ so $3(-6) \equiv 1 \pmod{19}$ and the inverse is $-6 \equiv 13.$

Comment: According to extended euclidean algorithm as specified here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ezHJ06dzIrs, the inverse should be 6. Why do we change it to -6. Is it because we need to bring - into the brackets, so "1 = 19 - 3(6)" actually becomes "1 = 19 + 3(-6)" and therefore the solution is -6. Is it always the case that we should have positive integer in front of the 3(x) and only x can be positive/negative?

Comment: Yes, bringing the negative inside the brackets and writing in the form $1 = 1(19) + (-6)(3)$ would always give you the correct answer. I believe in your video he doesn't do this for the second term because in the example he works out he's looking for the inverse of the first number mod the second so he doesn't have to care about the sign on the second term, whereas here you have it written the other way around. In any case for safety I would recommend always writing in the form $ax + by = 1$ and then you can use the result both ways.

Comment: Thank you. If you care to make it into an actual answer, I would be glad to confirm it into correct answer?

Comment: Sure thing, I'll get right on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from where you ended: $1 = 19 - 3(6)$ implies that $-3(6) = 3(-6) \equiv 1 \pmod{19},$ so the modular inverse of $3$ is $-6 \equiv 13.$ We can double-check this with $3 \cdot 13 = 39 = 2(19) + 1 \equiv 1.$

In order to avoid this confusion in the future, it may help to write your final decomposition in the form of $ax + by = 1.$ Taking mods on both sides it should be clear that we have $ax \equiv 1 \pmod{y}$ and $by \equiv 1 \pmod{x},$ so $a \equiv x^{-1} \pmod{y}$ and $b \equiv y^{-1} \pmod{x}.$